# Command Line Tools Not Found MacOS Monterey XCode13

Tags: macos, xcode-command-line-tools, xcode13

I´m currently trying to resign a wrapped app from mobileiron with terminal.

When I try it says:

"sign_wrapped_app.sh Version 4.7.0.0
Usage: sign_wrapped_app.sh -i  [-b  -e  -p  -s   -d  -o ] 
This script MUST be run on a computer with Xcode command-line tools installed.
jonasromankiewicz@MacBook-Pro-von-Jonas wrapping %"

I have MacOS Monterey on my MacBook Pro M1 2020
Xcode 13 Beta & I downloaded and installed CLT from the apple developer homepage.
I have the latest Version of Node, Homebrew, Ionic, Cordova installed.
I have tried to switch path. I have tried to reinstall CLT.
Also tried the Rosetta way...

Nothing worked. PLS Help :D

Thanks

Comment: Try running `xcode-select --install` in your Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Try to select your [Command Line Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwNfv.png) in Xcode Preferences (⌘+, -> Locations)

Comment: I saw something similar, macOS Monterey 12.4, Xcode 13.4.1, while trying to install software (OpenCV)  with Homebrew. It said “Error: gcc: the bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed.”   But when I tried to run `xcode-select --install` it said “xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates” I had installed the latest Xcode earlier today. The “Locations” in Preferences shows the version corresponding to my Xcode (13.4.1).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling **both** Xcode and CommandLineTools fixed the issue for me.

What I did:

- Delete `Xcode.app`.
- Delete CLT (`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`).
- Download Xcode and CLT from [Apple developer downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/). I installed the exact same version.
- Install Xcode and then the CLT.

Reinstalling just CLT did not resolve the issue.

[Related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401899/homebrew-your-clt-does-not-support-macos-11-0) [issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396818/upgrade-to-big-sur-beta-3-broke-brew-build-system/396926) that helped me find the solution.